# R 3.3.1 crashing with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have recently updated RStudio to 3.3.1, and since then, when I run the following code using dplyr, R tells me "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way".

```
max_trop <- df %>% group_by(record_id) %>% summarise(max= max(troponin, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Would anyone be able to tell me if I'm doing something particularly stupid? It used to work fine...

Many thanks

sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1 
locale:[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  
LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C   
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.5.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5   R6_2.1.2       assertthat_0.1 DBI_0.4-1     
 tools_3.3.1        tibble_1.1     Rcpp_0.12.6
```

Comment: post your sessionInfo()

Comment: Are you certain that each of the variables specified in the group_by() and summarise() are present in your data set? I get RStudio crashes when I mistype variable names working with dplyr.

Comment: 3.3.1 is the R version. Are you using the latest version of Rstudio? (shouldn't be a problem, but ...)

Comment: detach and then reinstall both Rcpp and dplyr (detach dplyr first, then when reinstalling, install Rcpp first. If that doesn't work then try reinstalling dplyr first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be caused by getting the wrong variable names in a dplyr chain. The solution is to check what you're providing in the variables exists in your data set.

```
data("mtcars")
library(dplyr)

# Runs
mtcars %>% summarise(mean(mpg))

# crashes with message 'This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.'
mtcars %>% summarise(mean(mag))
```

Comment: Thank you @r.bot. The variable names are definitely correct, and it has worked before on the same dataset

Comment: I've fixed it thank you. I think it wasn't working because the first troponin is missing for a few records. When I removed these records it runs. It has worked before with missing values though, so I'm confused why it was upset. Thank you all for your help